# Using value inside MergeMany operator in another pipeline

Tags: swift, combine

I created this function for decoding locally saved data.

```
private func getLocalCertificates(_ data: [CovidCertificateEntity]) -> [CovidCertificateDomainItem]? {
    var newCertificates: [CovidCertificateDomainItem]?
    
    Publishers
        .MergeMany(
            data.map { result -> AnyPublisher<Result<EUDCC, ErrorType>, Never> in
                self.certificateToDelete = result.qrCodeValue ?? ""
                return repository.getCertificateDetails(result.qrCodeValue ?? "")
            })
        .map { result -> CovidCertificateDomainItem? in
            switch result {
            case .success(let eudcc):
                do {
                    return try CovidCertificateDomainItem(eudcc: eudcc, qrCode: self.certificateToDelete)
                }
                catch {
                    return nil
                }
                
            case.failure(_):
                return nil
            }
        }
        .compactMap { $0 }
        .collect()
        .sink { result in
            newCertificates = result.reversed()
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)
    
    return newCertificates
}
```

I wanted to achieve that value *result* from *data.map* inside *MergeMany* operator is proceeded to *.map* operator, so I can use it in constructor of *CovidCertificateDomainItem*

I tried to made this with help variable *certificateToDelete*, but it always have last value from *data.map*.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a tuple. Instead of returning

```
repository.getCertificateDetails(result.qrCodeValue ?? "")
```

return a tuple:

```
(result, repository.getCertificateDetails(result.qrCodeValue ?? ""))
```

You will have many other adjustments to make in order to achieve that, but when you do, you'll be able to receive that tuple in `map` and thus have all the data you need.